# Missing data in SFrame

Tags: graphlab

I'm trying to use graphlab.linear_regression.create and I get an error that I have missing data in the column I am using to predict my model and it says to use dropna to fix the problem.  I use dropna but it doesn't get rid of any of the rows missing values.  I am typing ti_train.dropna() to try and drop the missing data and age_model = graphlab.linear_regression.create(ti_train, target='Survived', features=['Age'],validation_set=None) for my linear regression.  I've also tried fillna with ti_train.fillna('Age', np.median(ti_train['Age'])).  I got my data by reading a csv file into an SFrame. Thank you

Comment: What language is this? Python? If you add the language tag the question will get more attention from people who know how to help.

Answer (score 0):

just executing this code won't modify your sframe (assuming you are running ipython notebook with sframe)

```
ti_train.fillna('Age', np.median(ti_train['Age']))
```

Have you tried this (LHS for modifying the sframe) and then try running regression

```
ti_train = ti_train.fillna('Age', np.median(ti_train['Age']))
```